# Ember failed to find watchman

Tags: ember.js

When I run `ember test` I got this

`Could not start watchman`

I can confirm that I have installed watchman, when I run `which -a watchman`, I got

`/usr/local/bin/watchman`

Am I missing something?

Fyi

`ember -v` return

```
ember-cli: 2.15.1
node: 8.6.0
os: linux x64
```

Comment: could you run $watchman -v  from terminal without using sudo?

Comment: @YusufIbrahim yes I can. `watchman -v` returns `4.9.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reinstall watchman

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ git checkout v4.9.0  # the latest stable release
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source)

Answer (score 0):

Now, above process fails with error [bser.cpp:345:17: error: offset of on non-standard-layout type 'json_object_t'](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/57387) in step `make` on macos, just upgraded to 10.15.6 catalina due to xcode upgrade issue, cmdline tools `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)`

Patching with [these changes](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/commit/28a70a81e70ea5919938958ce48112eafe24154c) made it work to install watchman successfully tagedg `v4.9.0`